# Reverse proxy nginx with Docker

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, lets-encrypt

I have a website with a Docker container. 
So I use the nginx reverse proxy docker with let's encrypt 
I follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/pixelfordinner/pixelcloud-docker-apps/blob/master/nginx-proxy/docker-compose.yml)

But my website is not working with https.

There is my docker compose file:

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: pixelfordinner/nginx
    container_name: pixelcloud-nginx_proxy-nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "./volumes/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro"
      - "./volumes/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:ro"
      - "./volumes/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro"
      - "/usr/share/nginx/html"
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/docker-gen
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    volumes_from:
      - nginx
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./data/templates:/etc/docker-gen/templates:ro"
      - "./volumes/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:rw"
    entrypoint: /usr/local/bin/docker-gen -notify-sighup pixelcloud-nginx_proxy-nginx -watch -wait 5s:30s /etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  letsencrypt-nginx-proxy:
    restart: always
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: ssl
    depends_on:
      - nginx
      - nginx-proxy
    volumes_from:
      - nginx
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./volumes/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:rw"
      - "./volumes/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw"
    environment:
      - "NGINX_DOCKER_GEN_CONTAINER=pixelcloud-nginx_proxy-docker_gen"
   wordpress:
     image: wordpress
     environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=foo.example.com 
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=foo.example.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL= mail@example.com
```

I download the nginx.tmpl file from github, and copy it into /data/templates/nginx.tmpl

I don't inderstand what it is not working

Thanks for help!

**UPDATE:** I managed to setup https instead of http on wordpress.
But I have a Gitlab instance with docker compose. On the login page, the https is working, but when I login and go on the project homepage, there is https but the connection is not secure.
I would like this: https://gitlab.exemple.com

Comment: Can you explain what isn't working? Are you getting connection refused? Is it a white page with a 500 error? Is it something else?

Comment: With https, I have err_connection_reset error and with http, I have 502 bad gateway error

Comment: Without let's encrypt container, foo.example.com is working, I can surf on my website

Comment: Can you post your nginx config?

Comment: Also, as a side-note: Traefik is REALLY good at automating this stuff for you. Take a look :)

Comment: I have no nginx config file. I use only nginx with Docker

Comment: I only use the Docker compose file.

Comment: I not use other file from nginx proxy on github.

Comment: Thanks for sharing traefig, but I still use nginx!

Comment: Why is your connection not secure? Because the domain name doesn't match your SSL certificate domain name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the `jwilder/docker-gen` container that is required by `jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion`.

See documentation: https://github.com/JrCs/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion#separate-containers-recommended-method

See example: https://github.com/fatk/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion-examples/blob/master/docker-compose/v2/simple-site/docker-compose.yml

It means you will have to add a [nginx.tmpl](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/blob/master/nginx.tmpl) file and mount it to your `jwilder/docker-gen` container.
You will also need to share the `/etc/nginx/vhost.d` volume from the `nginx-proxy` container.

**Update:** 
The `container_name` of your service running the `docker-gen` image should be `pixelcloud-nginx_proxy-docker_gen` as it needs to match the `NGINX_DOCKER_GEN_CONTAINER` environment variable. So you should have:

```
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/docker-gen
    container_name: pixelcloud-nginx_proxy-docker_gen
```

Comment: Yes I forgot the nginx.tmpl file.

Comment: But even this file, and follow fatk docker compose file, it still not working. (I delete networks).

Comment: @Vana Please update your question with your updated docker-compose file. The logs (`docker-compose logs`) could also be useful.

Comment: I update my first post and follow this tutorial https://github.com/pixelfordinner/pixelcloud-docker-apps

Comment: @Vana See my answer update. Please make this change and let me know how it goes. Did you also copy the volumes from the pixelcloud-docker-apps git repository? https://github.com/pixelfordinner/pixelcloud-docker-apps/tree/master/nginx-proxy

Comment: Thanks for your update, my wordpress website is working on https but my gitlab instance don't. I have upate my post

Comment: All is working, a gitlab configuration was missing, I add it, and all gitlab pages are on https! Thanks for taking your time!